# QGIS 3 imports DATE type colum in Oracle Database as QDate, losing hh:mm:ss

Tags: qgis, import, oracle-dbms, qgis-3, qgsvectorlayer

I am at the moment working on a lift for an QGIS 2 plugin to work with QGIS 3.

The plugin specifies a `QgsDataSourceUri` and uses it in an `QgsVectorLayer`.
In the specific table, laying in an `Oracle` database, there is a column which is *not* named 'date' but a german name.
The type of that column is DATE type, therefore containing year, month, day, hour, minute and second.

In QGIS 2.10 this column was automatically converted to an `QDateTime` object by the constructor. 
In QGIS 3.4.2 however this column is converted to `QDate`, losing the hours, minutes and seconds by that.

In the documentation I cannot find any explanation on how to specify the way a column is converted to prevent that data loss.

**Am I missing an configuration option that achieves to specify the conversion of a column?**

The loading procedure looks like this:

```
def fetch_layer(self):        
    uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
    uri.setConnection(self.host, self.port, self.db_name, self.usr, self.pswd)
    uri.setDataSource(self.schema, self.table, "SHAPE", "username=\'{}\'".format(self.usr))
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), self.layername, "oracle")
    print(f"This should not be QDate : {type(next(layer.getFeatures()).attribute(self.date_attr))}")
```

For the case that this is indeed a bug, I created also a bug report at [QGIS Tickts](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20739)

Comment: You don't seem to have a question in your Question.

Comment: Uhh, you are right. The question is, basically 'Am I missing something?'.
But that should be written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/28559) was finally adressed in [this PR](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36397).

The issue was part of the [3.14.0 milestone](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/milestone/96) and should therefor be solved in QGis 3.14.